# Async/await order issue in web3.js callback

Tags: javascript, async-await, web3js

The problem is showing I'm using 2 async function one by one. Each of them calls the method from the smart contract and doing other staff on 'receipt' callback.

The code is:

```
await first()
await second()

let first = async function () {
   await myContract.methods.methodOne()
   .send({from: account})
   .on('receipt', async () => {
    console.log('1')
    async someAsyncFunction()
   })
}

let second = async function () {
   await myContract.methods.methodOne()
   .send({from: account})
   .on('receipt', async () => {
    console.log('2')
    console.log(variableFromContract) // undefined
   })
}

let someAsyncFunction = async function () {
   setTimeout(() => {
      variableFromContract = 10;
   }, 2000);
}
```

What's the problem with someAsyncFunction?
Why it's not running before the second() function?

Thanks in advance.
(I'm using web3.js 1.0.0-beta.37 version)

Comment: Just to double check- you debugged the code and function itself is not called and not set timeout callback comes after the second call?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the function someAsyncFunction()  works, but after function second().

Comment: That all is very strange - `async someAsyncFunction()` should be invalid syntax - very confusing what you tried to express with that... And that 2 second timeout - what is it for and what you expect to happen there?

Comment: you are right, someAsyncFunction() in this case just an async method, but in a real project, it's call the methods from smart contract asynchronously. The problem is that someAsyncFunction() bring with itself a variable from the smart contract, which is necessary for second() function, but in my case, it's worked after second().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after many tries, no needed put an async method inside 'receipt' callback, just use

```
...
.on('receipt', () => {
    console.log('block mined') 
})
.then( async () => { 
    await someAsyncFunction() // put the code here
})
```

Comment: `async`/`await` is generally used instead of directly using promises with `.then`... are you sure you need it at all?

Comment: yes, I think I need to optimize the code one more time

Answer (score 0):

A few issues here:

```
let first = async function () {
   await myContract.methods.methodOne()
   .send({from: account})
   .on('receipt', async () => {
    console.log('1')
    async someAsyncFunction() // <--- should be return await someAsyncFunction() so you have a value to pass onto second
   })
}

let second = async function () {
   await myContract.methods.methodOne()
   .send({from: account})
   .on('receipt', async () => { // <-- this is an async function but you don't await anything inside of it
    console.log('2')
    console.log(variableFromContract) // undefined
   })
}

let someAsyncFunction = async function () { // again async function but awaiting nothing to resolve.
   setTimeout(() => {
      variableFromContract = 10;
   }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: `second()` *will not* be called before `await first()` completely finishes - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function. Suggestion in this post is strange and confusing and does not address the fact that 
 `variableFromContract` is set about 2 seconds *after* `first` finishes due to strange `setTimeout`.

Comment: Good catch. JSFiddle here documenting the correct order of operations. http://jsfiddle.net/dotexe0/p4k8zsw1/